# Recover Hexxit world with region files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I found the region files (MCA) from my lost Minecraft Hexxit world and wanted to use them to recover the world. I created an empty world and replaced its region files with the ones from my lost world, but when opened it, it didn't do anything. I then tried viewing my lost world region files with this tool: https://github.com/Pessimistress/minecraft-chunk-viewer but it crashed. It also didn't work in MCedit.

I just don't get why these region files would be corrupted (maybe because my lost world was built on a server?). It'd be very kind of you to have a look at these, here's everything that I found: https://www.dropbox.com/s/whsotwvx7211hx5/5_62_68_162_25565.zip?dl=0

I am playing on Minecraft for PC. The original map was on version 1.0.5 and I've downgraded my own game to the same version (I tried many things). However, I don't think it's a problem with the version as it doesn't show up in the Minecraft Chunk Viewer online.

Comment: What Version of Minecraft did your original Hexxit map come from? and What version of Minecraft are you trying to load the map in? (Both Edition and Version Number)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Malco! :) It was version 1.0.5 and I've downgraded my own game to the same version (I tried many things). And it's Minecraft for PC. However, I don't think it's a problem with the version as it doesn't show up in the Minecraft Chunk Viewer online.

Comment: No problem, not an answer though :). Just trying to get a bit more information so that someone who knows more will be able to answer it. When you do get an answer it will show up below

Comment: I have also edited your Question to include the info from your comments, feel free to modify it if you think there is anything else that people may find useful. Oh, and Welcome to the site!

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty new to this and all :) Thanks for the help and the warm welcome!

Comment: Hi Bro5ever. I am unable to find a level.dat file anywhere on the dropbox. A *level.dat* file is essential for minecraft to load a world

https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Level_format